# Excluir dados do banco de dados após 20 minutos

Tags: php, mysql

Colegas.

Estou finalizando uma loja virtual, porém o cliente vai trabalhar com estoques. A proposta é que após 20 minutos de ociosidade desse usuário, os produtos sejam excluídos automaticamente do carrinho para o estoque não ficar preso em um abandono de carrinho.

A exclusão dos dados estou fazendo pelo PHP e até aqui está tudo ok. Consegui também pelo CPanel configurar a tarefa cron para meu script PHP.

Os cadastros do carrinho, estou armazenando a data no campo DATETIME(), como eu faria para comparar o campo da data com mais 20 minutos e após isso executar a query de exclusão?

Pensei em algo dessa forma:

```
SELECT DataAbertura, ADDTIME( DataAbertura,  '1 0:20:0:0.0000' ) AS DataVinte
FROM  `loja
```

Comment: O correto é todo o código estar no seu servidor e ser executado por um cron. Mas aqui, eu vou dar uma sugestão. Não apague os dados. Use uma flag para marcar que esse produto está novamente disponível, mas deixe o dado lá no banco. Essa é uma estratégia para permitir que a loja ofereça o mesmo produto mais tarde, caso o cliente não tenha comprado. Se você apagar, essa informação pode ser perdida.

Comment: Olá Eduardo. Concordo com você em relação a não excluir os dados do banco, porém o cliente infelizmente não tem interesse em oferecer o mesmo produto para o cliente no caso do abandono do carrinho.

Comment: Serio? que tipo de negocio é esse que não tem nais interesse de vender se não for co prado em 20min? E se o usuario acessar de outra maquina? ou nem se quer estiver logado?

Comment: É porque ele trabalha com poucos estoques Celsom e infelizmente o cliente sempre está certo, por mais que mostramos para ele a solução correta. Mas a decisão do cliente não é o mérito do post.

Comment: @Fox.11 Sim, mas por isso que fiz outras perguntas. Como você faz essa verificação? Pois se eu não estiver logado, você não sabe quem eu sou, ou se acessar de outra máquina, os meus dados não estarão em `storage`.

Comment: Alguns colegas armazenam os produtos do carrinho em sessões/cookies até a finalização da compra. Eu armazeno em uma tabela de banco de dados e uso o mesmo raciocínio do eduardosouza, porém até onde sei, é  impossível ver de outra máquina as compras do carrinho sem estar logado, não vejo como. Abra uma loja virtual qualquer, coloque uma compra no carrinho, depois abra outro navegador e acesse a mesma loja virtual. Verá que seu carrinho estará vazio. Mas se cadastre e faça o acesso. Algumas lojas armazenam em sessões o carrinho outras em BD. Eu uso a segunda opção.